# Creating PySpark Dataframe from Spotify API Call

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spotify, spotipy

I'm currently learning more about pySpark and wanted to put a project together that will place spotify api data into a spark dataframe for analysis.

I'm familiar with how to do this within Pandas and thought the approach would be similiar, but I quickly realized that was not the case here. I've checked other SO questions but still haven't found an approach that works for me yet.

The code that I currently have looks like this:

```
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials, SpotifyOAuth
import datetime
import os

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, types
from pyspark import SparkContext,SparkConf


# Extract Data
def get_data():

        CLIENT_ID = os.environ.get('SP_CLIENT_ID')
        CLIENT_SEC = os.environ.get('SP_CLIENT_SECRET')

        scope = "user-library-read user-read-recently-played"

        today = datetime.datetime.now()
        yesterday = today - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        yesterday_unix_timestamp = int(yesterday.timestamp()) * 1000

        client_creds_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=CLIENT_ID,client_secret=CLIENT_SEC)
        sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(client_id=CLIENT_ID,client_secret=CLIENT_SEC,scope=scope,redirect_uri='http://localhost:3000/callback'))
        
        return sp.current_user_recently_played(after=yesterday_unix_timestamp, limit=30)

# Transform Data in pyspark
def transform():

    data = get_data()

    song_names = []
    artist_names = []
    played_at = []
    timestamps = []

    for song in data['items']:
        song_names.append(song['track']['name'])
        artist_names.append(song['track']['album']['artists'][0]['name'])
        played_at.append(song['played_at'])
        timestamps.append(song['played_at'][0:10])

    song_dict = {
        'song_names': song_names,
        'artist_names': artist_names,
        'played_at': played_at,
        'timestamps': timestamps
    }

    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Spotify').getOrCreate()

    sc = spark.sparkContext

    json_rdd = sc.parallelize(song_dict)

    df = spark.read.json(json_rdd, multiLine=True)

    df.show(truncate=False)

transform()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, spark is a fun technology to learn and loading api data is something I'd like to really understand.

Thanks!

Comment: what is the problem you encountered?

Comment: I didn't encounter an error at all persay...but I did see a "_corrupted-record" though. That's what I didn't really understand how to fix.

Answer (score 0):

So you have multiple Python's lists and you want to create a Spark's DataFrame. You should use `createDataFrame` method of SparkSession.

```py
songs = "a b c x y z".split()
names = "i h k l m n".split()
df = spark.createDataFrame(zip(songs,names),['songs','names'])
df.show()
```

And you'll get a Spark's DataFrame `df` like this:

```
+-----+-----+
|songs|names|
+-----+-----+
|    a|    i|
|    b|    h|
|    c|    k|
|    x|    l|
|    y|    m|
|    z|    n|
+-----+-----+
```